# How can i Read a file in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, readfile

I´m new to rails an i try to read a txt.file that looks like this:

> ThomasLinde ; PeterParker ; Monday
>
> JulkoAndrovic ; KeludowigFrau ; Tuesday
>
> JohannesWoellenstein ; SiegmundoKrugmando ; Wednesday

Now i want to read each "column" of the .txt file to display it on a page of my application.
My idea for the code looks like this:

```
if (File.exist?("Zuordnung_x.txt"))
   fi=File.open("Zuordnung_x.txt", "r")
   fi.each { |line|
      sa=line.split(";")
      @nanny_name=sa[0]
      @customer_name=sa[1]
      @period_name=sa[2]
   }
   fi.close
else
   @nanny_name=nil
   @customer_name=nil
   @period_name=nil
   flash.now[:not_available] = "Nothing happened!"
end
```

This is my Idea but he gives me only one line. Any ideas? or i am just able to read one line if i use `@nanny_name`?

Comment: You need to store the data in an array or a hash, by using variables you're overwriting the variables as you process each line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only need a variable with an array value, and push every line to it.

```
@result = []
if (File.exist?("Zuordnung_x.txt"))
  fi=File.open("Zuordnung_x.txt", "r")
  fi.each do |line|
    sa=line.split(";")
    @result << {nanny_name: sa[0], customer_name: sa[1], period_name: [2]}
  end
  fi.close
else
  flash.now[:not_available] = "Nothing happened!"
end
```

and on view template, you need to each `@result`, example

```
<% @result.each do |row| %>
   <p><%= "#{row[:nanny_name]} serve the customer #{row[:customer_name]} on #{row[:period_name]}"  %><p>
<% end %>
```

optional :

If just using `split`, probably you will get some string with whitespace at the beginning of string or at the end of string

```
"ThomasLinde ; PeterParker ; Monday".split(';')
 => ["ThomasLinde ", " PeterParker ", " Monday"]
```

to handle it, you need `strip` every value of an array like this :

```
"ThomasLinde ; PeterParker ; Monday".split(';').map(&:strip)
 => ["ThomasLinde", "PeterParker", "Monday"]
```

Comment: Great! This works for now. Do you have an idea how to Display the results with text in it like :
The nanny `@nanny_name` serve the customer `@customer_name` on `@period_name`? and a paragraph after each row ?

Comment: Glad to help, like what?

Comment: @Feidex You can use tring interpolation `#{variable}`.. check my updated answer.